# Adding custom column to a SharePoint library using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, sharepoint-library, graph-api, ms-graph-client

I want to be able to add a custom column to a SharePoint library using Graph API.

I was able to create the library using article `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http`. But, I don't find any information on adding custom column after the library is created.

I tried to do PUT and PATCH operation but it throws 400 Bad Request. I also checked below article `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http` but it doesn't tell any way to adding a custom column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `POST` method like:

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns
```

**Example request**:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "test",
  "enforceUniqueValues": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "indexed": false,
  "name": "Title",
  "text": {
    "allowMultipleLines": false,
    "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
    "linesForEditing": 0,
    "maxLength": 255
  }
}
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Create columnDefinition for a list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-post-columns?view=graph-rest-beta)

---

**Note**: Currently this is available for Microsoft Graph REST API Beta version.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful and it created the column. Also I checked that v1.0 too creates the column but yesterday it was giving 400 Bad Request error. May be I had some issue with JSON. I used the JSON from the format above and it worked.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.